# Rails no database name in connection

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Trying to run a rails app in prod on Ubuntu 16.04 and installed mysql `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24`, Ruby `2.5.3`, and using the `mysql2` gem. It works fine on my Mac 10.13. My Rails app can't seem to read the DB name in Ubuntu.

Can't find the DB name:

`{:adapter=>"mysql2", :encoding=>"utf8", :database=>nil, :username=>"myUser", :password=>"secret", :host=>"127.0.0.1", :port=>3306}`

Then adds 127.0.0.1 as the DB name:

`{:adapter=>"mysql2", :encoding=>"utf8", :database=>"127.0.0.1", :username=>"myUser", :password=>"secret", :host=>"127.0.0.1", :port=>3306}`

My database.yml

`production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: mydb
  username: myUser
  password: secret
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306`

I've been pulling my hair out as to why I can't connect to the DB in my Ubuntu server. I can log into mysql through the CLI fine with the DB user fine.

I'm also seeing the same issue on an Ubuntu box with Vagrant so thats consistent.

Any help is extremely appreciative at this time.

I have no idea but putting it in this format works. I tried everything else, different DB name, etc to no avail:

`production:
     url: mysql2://user:pass@localhost/myDb`

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: How about showing your `database.yml`?

Comment: db name `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: How does the rest of your database.yml look like? Are you sure you're running the server in production mode?

Answer (score 0):

Your database.yml should look something like this:

```
development:
  adapter:  mysql2
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: mysql_user
  password: your_password
  host:     localhost_or_your_host
  database: db_name
```

Do change your environment to match your requirements. This will work for your development mode.